# Invalid context when drawing bezierPath on CAShapeLayer

Tags: swift, calayer

So I get these error when running my code:

```
CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor: invalid context 0x0. If you want to see the backtrace, please set CG_CONTEXT_SHOW_BACKTRACE environmental variable.
CGContextSaveGState: invalid context 0x0. If you want to see the backtrace, please set CG_CONTEXT_SHOW_BACKTRACE environmental variable.
CGContextSetLineWidth: invalid context 0x0. If you want to see the backtrace, please set CG_CONTEXT_SHOW_BACKTRACE environmental variable.
CGContextSetLineJoin: invalid context 0x0. If you want to see the backtrace, please set CG_CONTEXT_SHOW_BACKTRACE environmental variable.
CGContextSetLineCap: invalid context 0x0. If you want to see the backtrace, please set CG_CONTEXT_SHOW_BACKTRACE environmental variable.
CGContextSetMiterLimit: invalid context 0x0. If you want to see the backtrace, please set CG_CONTEXT_SHOW_BACKTRACE environmental variable.
CGContextSetFlatness: invalid context 0x0. If you want to see the backtrace, please set CG_CONTEXT_SHOW_BACKTRACE environmental variable.
CGContextAddPath: invalid context 0x0. If you want to see the backtrace, please set CG_CONTEXT_SHOW_BACKTRACE environmental variable.
CGContextDrawPath: invalid context 0x0. If you want to see the backtrace, please set CG_CONTEXT_SHOW_BACKTRACE environmental variable.
CGContextRestoreGState: invalid context 0x0. If you want to see the backtrace, please set CG_CONTEXT_SHOW_BACKTRACE environmental variable.
```

When I set the CG_CONTEXT_SHOW_BACKTRACE environment variable, the error points to my `func bezierPath(dentInMM value: Float) -> CGPath` function. Here are the code fragments that make up this part of my controller:

```
var shape = CAShapeLayer()

func someFunc() {
  self.dentView.layer.addSublayer(self.shape)

  let color: UIColor = .systemGreen
  self.shape.fillColor = color.withAlphaComponent(0.3).cgColor
  self.shape.strokeColor = color.cgColor
  self.shape.lineWidth = 6
  self.shape.path = self.bezierPath(dentInMM: 0)
}

func bezierPath(dentInMM value: Float) -> CGPath {
    self.shape.frame = self.dentView.bounds

    let x000 = Int(self.shape.frame.minX)
    let x050 = Int(self.shape.frame.midX)
    let x100 = Int(self.shape.frame.maxX)
    let x010 = x100 / 10
    let x040 = x050 - x010
    let x060 = x050 + x010
    let yOffSet = Int(self.shape.frame.minY)

    let indentation = Int(value * self.dentDisplayMultiplier)

    let bezierPath = UIBezierPath()
    bezierPath.move(to: CGPoint(x: x000, y: yOffSet))
    bezierPath.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: x050, y: indentation), controlPoint1: CGPoint(x: x050, y: yOffSet), controlPoint2: CGPoint(x: x040, y: indentation))
    bezierPath.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: x100, y: yOffSet), controlPoint1: CGPoint(x: x060, y: indentation), controlPoint2: CGPoint(x: x050, y: yOffSet))
    UIColor.label.setStroke()
    bezierPath.stroke()

    return bezierPath.cgPath
}
```

Do I need to specify a context somewhere?
I was under the impression that CAShapeLayer provides the context...

Comment: Don’t call `bezierPath.stroke()` . You are providing a path to the layer, not drawing the path.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

dont have to call drawing methods

> bezierPath.stroke()

The CAShapeLayer will draw itself in the dentView

and do you really need

> UIColor.label.setStroke()

as you have already have set the strokeColor in someFunc()

Here is what worked without error:

```
class ThirdViewController: UIViewController {
    let dentDisplayMultiplier : Float = 6
    var shape = CAShapeLayer()

    @IBOutlet weak var dentView: UIView!


    func someFunc() {
      self.dentView.layer.addSublayer(self.shape)

      let color: UIColor = .systemGreen
      self.shape.fillColor = color.withAlphaComponent(0.3).cgColor
      self.shape.strokeColor = color.cgColor
      self.shape.lineWidth = 6
      self.shape.path = self.bezierPath(dentInMM: 3)
    }

    func bezierPath(dentInMM value: Float) -> CGPath {
        self.shape.frame = self.dentView.bounds

        let x000 = Int(self.shape.frame.minX)
        let x050 = Int(self.shape.frame.midX)
        let x100 = Int(self.shape.frame.maxX)
        let x010 = x100 / 10
        let x040 = x050 - x010
        let x060 = x050 + x010
        let yOffSet = Int(self.shape.frame.minY)

        let indentation = Int(value * self.dentDisplayMultiplier)

        let bezierPath = UIBezierPath()
        bezierPath.move(to: CGPoint(x: x000, y: yOffSet))
        bezierPath.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: x050, y: indentation), controlPoint1: CGPoint(x: x050, y: yOffSet), controlPoint2: CGPoint(x: x040, y: indentation))
        bezierPath.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: x100, y: yOffSet), controlPoint1: CGPoint(x: x060, y: indentation), controlPoint2: CGPoint(x: x050, y: yOffSet))

        return bezierPath.cgPath
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {


        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        someFunc()

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
let bezierPath = UIBezierPath()

UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.shape.frame.size, false, 0)

bezierPath.move(to: CGPoint(x: x000, y: yOffSet))
bezierPath.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: x050, y: indentation), controlPoint1: CGPoint(x: x050, y: yOffSet), controlPoint2: CGPoint(x: x040, y: indentation))
bezierPath.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: x100, y: yOffSet), controlPoint1: CGPoint(x: x060, y: indentation), controlPoint2: CGPoint(x: x050, y: yOffSet))
UIColor.label.setStroke()
bezierPath.stroke()

UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
```